# How to apply CSS to only a particular class while the class shares other CSS code, with another class?

Tags: css, sass

For example here's the HTML code:

```
<div class="topSection">
    <div class="middleSection">
        <p>This is some text in a paragraph.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="lowerSection">
        <p>This is some text in a paragraph.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS

```
.topSection{
    .middleSection, .lowerSection{
        padding: 20px;
        font-size: 20px
        p{
            background-color: lightgrey;
        }
    }
}
```

With the way this CSS is structured, I was wondering if I want to apply the `p` tag style to ONLY for the `middleSection` class, but not for the `lowerSection` class, how would I do that?

I was thinking to do something like this by using the `:not()` but this did not work:

```
.topSection{
    .middleSection, .lowerSection{
        padding: 20px;
        font-size: 20px
        p:not(.lowerSection){
            background-color: lightgrey;
        }
    }
}
```

Or is the only way to do it is by creating separate CSS code for `middleSection` and then apply the `p` tag styles to it? To me this seems like extra bit of code, to address a small issue. Is there a shorter way to address this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `:not()` should apply to the parent so consider `&`

```css
.topSection {
  .middleSection,
  .lowerSection {
    padding: 20px;
    font-size: 20px;
    &:not(.lowerSection) p {
      background-color: lightgrey;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="topSection">
  <div class="middleSection">
    <p>This is some text in a paragraph.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="lowerSection">
    <p>This is some text in a paragraph.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't put the p styling into that part of the selection.

Just add a separate part which is for middleSection only:

```css
.topSection {
  .middleSection,
  .lowerSection {
    padding: 20px;
    font-size: 20px
  }
  .middleSection {
    p {
      background-color: lightgrey;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="topSection">
  <div class="middleSection">
    <p>This is some text in a paragraph.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="lowerSection">
    <p>This is some text in a paragraph.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I understand. So the only way to address this is by adding separate CSS for middleSection? I thought there might b a shorter way so I don't have to create separate CSS to address this.

Comment: I'm not saying it's the only way, but it seems to me the simplest way. And actually quite a standard way of doing things before we had nesting.

Answer (score -1):

It seems like a simple problem, but the scope of some styles is one of the most difficult things in CSS. It's a chronic problem, and finally we have some tools to solve it. I know there's a lot of code here, but like I said, it's not a simple problem. Maybe you can get some inspiration from these solutions.

You can use the`:has` pseudo-class selector to separate styles of `p` elements in the different classes:

```css
.middleSection:has(p) p {
  background-color: lightgrey;
```

Or you can use the `@scope` at-rule, which is the newest and better way to do this:

```css
@scope (.middleSection) to (.lowerSection) {
  p {
    background-color: lightgrey;
  }
```

The `@scope` at-rule has partial browser support, so you may not want to use this option, but it helps us a lot for future CSS.